# Setting height when exporting RDLC table with variable number of rows as image

Tags: c#, rdlc, report-viewer2010

I have RDLC report with simple table. I'm exporting report to image with `LocalReport.Render` method. Here I need to specify the height of the report in device info parameter. My device info string looks like this (parameters are set in `string.Format` method):

```
<DeviceInfo>
    <ColorDepth>{0}</ColorDepth>
    <DpiX>{1}</DpiX>
    <DpiY>{2}</DpiY>
    <MarginBottom>0in</MarginBottom>
    <MarginLeft>0in</MarginLeft>
    <MarginRight>0in</MarginRight>
    <MarginTop>0in</MarginTop>
    <OutputFormat>{3}</OutputFormat>
    <PageHeight>{4}in</PageHeight>
    <PageWidth>{5}in</PageWidth>
</DeviceInfo>
```

OutputFormat is set to "Image". Explanation of device info xml is [here](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms155373%28v=sql.90%29.aspx).

Since table has variable number of rows I don't want to set specific height, but I want report to calculate height of generated image. I could approximate the height by multiplying row height with number of rows, but sometimes my rows are not equal in height. Setting PageHeight to 0 generates image with fixed height (around 800px).

The same thing is with charts - I have to specify the height so image can be skewed.

Is there a way to let report generate itself with calculated height?

Comment: I just stumbled across your post looking for information about the deviceinfo tags. One thing that came to mind is if you could add some graphical object to the bottom of the report data. Then after the image is generated look through the image using the .net graphics routines and find where it is then crop the image in code. It's not overly elegant but could work.

Comment: @Kosta did you figure this out?

Comment: @MrZander I have no idea, was so long ago, but I think I didn't and ended up using something else (I don't remember what).

Comment: @Kosta Thanks.  I ended up calculating it myself... `rows * Hardrowheight`.  Not ideal if I ever change the height of the rows since it's hardcoded in the source, but I guess it's the best option I have.